# How to convert a retrained model to tflite format?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, pre-trained-model, transfer-learning

I have retrained an image classifier model on MobileNet, I have these files.
[image: Files generated on retraining]

Further, I used toco to compress the retrained model to convert the model to `.lite` format, but I need it in `.tflite` format. Is there anyway I can get to tflite format from existing files?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple python script which you can use to convert .pb format graph into tflite.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

graph_def_file = "output_graph.pb"  ##Your frozen graph

input_arrays = ["input"]         ##Input Node
output_arrays = ["final_result"] ##Output Node

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite","wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the .lite model to .tflite and it should work just fine.
Alternatively, with toco, you can rename the output as it is created :

```
toco \
  --input_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \ //change this to tflite
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shape=1,224,224,3 \
  --input_array=input \
  --output_array=final_result \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

Comment: lol @harshithdwivedi we interacted here before we met for GCI.

Comment: Lol! Small world ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert TensorFlow checkpoints and GraphDef to a TensorFlow Lite FlatBuffer:

1. Freeze the checkpoints and graph using [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)
2. Convert the frozen graph to a TensorFlow Lite FlatBuffer using
   [TOCO](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco#toco-tensorflow-lite-optimizing-converter).

Your `freeze_graph.py` command will look similar to the following:

```
freeze_graph -- \
--input_graph=output_graph.pb \
--input_binary=true \
--input_checkpoint=checkpoint \
--output_graph=frozen_graph.pb \
--output_node_names= MobilenetV1/Predictions/Softmax
```

You can use either [`TocoConverter`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/python_api.md) (Python API) or [`tflite_convert`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md) (command line tool) with your model. `TocoConverter` accepts a tf.Session, frozen graph def, SavedModel directory or a Keras model file. `tflite_convert` accepts the later three formats.

When using TOCO, specify the `output_file` parameter with a `.tflite` extension.